# Connecting Linux system to switch from 2 interfaces

Tags: linux, switch, high-availability, interface

To get proper redundancy, we've installed 2 switches in our network and connected them to eachother. We now want to hook our servers to both switches. Since all servers have 2 ethernet ports, this should be possible.

The big problem is that we want to do this using just 1 IP address per server. Does anyone know how to configure Linux (and Windows too actually) so it supports this, at the same time avoiding any form of looping ? I know it's possible to just set the IP on both interfaces, but that causes ARP issues when disconnecting 1 of the switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linux the simplest [bonding](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding) method to use is active-backup mode when connecting to two different switches.  With this only one is active at a time and you can set which one you want to have priority.  This method requires no special configuration on the switches.

With windows you are going to need to install a utility that comes from the vendor of your NICs.  For Broadcom NICs you want [Broadcom Advanced Control Suite (BACS)](http://w0.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/management_applications.php). Intel has a similar utility.  The bonding on Windows can cause problems with certain things (I.E. not a good idea on domain controllers from my experience).

Oh, and do set up STP or RSTP to prevent switching loops ... it is really quite easy usually.  Often something like `spanning-tree`

Answer (score 4):

Use [link aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation), which is otherwise known as bonding or teaming.  The exact methods of implementation vary depending upon the OS and distribution.

It will allow you to use both interfaces as a single interface, which will provide load balancing and enable high availability for the network interfaces.  It's highly configurable depending upon your exact specification.

Comment: Agreed. One thing to note, though, is that depending on which LA tech you use, it may require special configuration on the switch ports.

Answer (score 1):

In linux world you need to use the Network Bonding (a kernel module named bond).
In its documentation you can read all that you need to properly configure it in a redundant setup.

If I recall correctly, you also need switch support for it (in the form of [802.1D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1D) [Spanning Tree Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_protocol) or the like), so you won't be able to do that with standard unmanaged low-end switches. But I may be wrong here, please go check the documentation of the bond support and of you switch.

I know that Windows Server systems have a similar bonding feature. I don't know its details nor its availability on desktop systems.