# Connecting Linux system to switch from 2 interfaces

Tags: linux, interface, switch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting Linux system to switch from 2 interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/179584/connecting-linux-system-to-switch-from-2-interfaces)

To get proper redundancy, we've installed 2 switches in our network and connected them to eachother. We now want to hook our servers to both switches. Since all servers have 2 ethernet ports, this should be possible.

The big problem is that we want to do this using just 1 IP address per server. Does anyone know how to configure Linux (and Windows too actually) so it supports this, at the same time avoiding any form of looping ?

Comment: Doesn't feel like programming question to me.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux look at the [Linux Ethernet Bonding Driver](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-ethernet-bonding-driver-howto.php)

Answer (score 0):

What youre looking for is a type of [NLB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758834(WS.10).aspx) or "teaming". There are a variety of third party alternatives - most implemented by the MFG. I'd take a look at your MOBO's website for any multi-home/teaming tools. Compatibility with the switches is going to be your biggest hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to configure the Switches you can try the Mode 5 or balance-tlb.